# How to move items in a multidimensional array to any other random position?

Tags: python, arrays

Below shows a multidimensional array with 4 elements appended to it. How can i take one of these elements and move it to any other random place in the array. If the position already holds an element it should stay there.

```
    dimension = 2
    board = [[[[]for x in range(dimension)]
                 for x in range(dimension)]
                 for x in range(dimension)]
    board[0][0][0].append('test')
    board[1][0][0].append('test2')
    board[0][1][0].append('test3')
    board[1][1][0].append('test4')

    print(board)


[[[['test'], []], [['test3'], []]], [[['test2'], []], [['test4'], []]]]
#Printed list ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import random
dimension = 2
x = random.randint(0,dimension-1)
y = random.randint(0,dimension-1)
z = random.randint(0,dimension-1)

if not board[x][y][z]:
   board[x][y][z] = board[0][0][0]
   board[x][y][z] = []
```

Your question didn't specify if the source was random or chosen, so I just picked `board[0][0][0]`, if it is also random, you'll just need to get a random x, y, z for it too.